# merging an xts and a list together by index()

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I am trying to `merge` / `join` two objects together, one an [xts](/questions/tagged/xts) object and the other a list. I want to keep the data as an `xts` object (so merge the second data with the first data I post below). Basically, the `Data 2` consists of predicted probabilities from the `Data 1`.

I have tried creating Data 2 as a data.frame and unlisting it and then merging it `by = "index(data)"` but it fails.

The dimensions of the data are the following:

```
dim(dat)
 212 4

prob_predictions <- as.data.frame(unlist(probs))
dim(prob_predictions)

 191 1
```

I am also trying subset(index(df1) %in% index(df2))

Data 1:

```
dat <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1157.4779907, 1161.2739868, 1165.064978, 1162.5039794, 
1152.5029784, 1143.5659789, 1131.9999755, 1115.114978, 1101.3089843, 
1088.9449828, 1077.7859863, 1067.7619873, 1059.9439942, 1058.2339967, 
1062.8999879, 1065.9739869, 1071.7789918, 1084.3059937, 1094.9029908, 
1101.5380006, 1106.801001, 1106.7830079, 1105.7230103, 1105.3360108, 
1104.5960206, 1104.4260255, 1106.363025, 1109.688025, 1111.763025, 
1113.7510255, 1118.2270265, 1126.2330201, 1131.9140137, 1132.8030029, 
1133.0679931, 1131.1919921, 1123.4999877, 1109.6529845, 1098.5239806, 
1085.2169738, 1070.7239746, 1058.9449829, 1046.018982, 1037.3779847, 
1030.1209901, 1023.8139955, 1019.6099977, 1018.9979982, 1016.8410036, 
1018.3280031, 1021.1230043, 1020.8710024, 1024.0220033, 1030.0970094, 
1034.7910035, 1040.7799927, 1047.371991, 1052.5719849, 1051.4059814, 
1051.5269836, 1052.2799865, 1052.3579894, 1050.2929931, 1046.6079956, 
1041.8380005, 1035.4400025, 1032.9650025, 1031.6990113, 1035.0920167, 
1041.2500184, 1047.0030091, 1053.8240052, 1062.1109986, 1066.3029907, 
1072.0419922, 1077.5289917, 1079.3439941, 1081.8229858, 1083.4049804, 
1083.0979735, 1081.2649779, 1079.0049803, 1075.0169798, 1073.8739867, 
1074.1959837, 1078.2869871, 1085.5799925, 1091.5880003, 1098.3030028, 
1102.7200072, 1106.8830077, 1112.3160033, 1120.2160033, 1126.9150023, 
1133.6280028, 1136.9040038, 1140.320996, 1143.1609985, 1146.4569946, 
1149.8369995, 1153.297998, 1152.7800049, 1150.6940064, 1147.6130005, 
1143.8229981, 1140.1619995, 1135.5619995, 1129.0449951, 1124.4880005, 
1122.7390015, 1122.5960084, 1125.3989991, 1128.9430054, 1136.8930054, 
1144.3530029, 1151.173999, 1158.3080078, 1167.6070068, 1173.8760009, 
1178.3499999, 1183.494995, 1193.018994, 1203.9989867, 1212.4839843, 
1217.4519897, 1221.0399902, 1222.8859863, 1225.2989868, 1229.2179931, 
1233.0979858, 1235.0249878, 1234.4389893, 1232.6299927, 1230.7069947, 
1230.6179932, 1232.1449952, 1234.6289918, 1234.0659913, 1232.0999879, 
1229.8249879, 1228.1249879, 1224.0649903, 1220.2369874, 1215.8649903, 
1214.1689942, 1214.8499878, 1213.7549926, 1217.246997, 1220.5099975, 
1222.2329955, 1221.1559935, 1219.641992, 1216.0529905, 1211.9979856, 
1206.3969847, 1199.9509886, 1193.1179808, 1185.7209715, 1179.0619749, 
1172.8479857, 1169.2699828, 1167.7309814, 1169.2739868, 1169.3999878, 
1170.2729858, 1171.0019897, 1172.7689941, 1174.7, 1176.7939942, 
1180.7199952, 1184.6089966, 1187.7949951, 1185.9269897, 1185.0529907, 
1182.6129883, 1178.0299805, 1168.1029786, 1156.5709717, 1148.2319702, 
1137.9259643, 1130.0429687, 1121.3169677, 1113.2949707, 1107.2059692, 
1102.4249755, 1098.911975, 1095.860974, 1097.485974, 1093.6249755, 
1086.4079772, 1077.9009704, 1074.0089783, 1072.2119812, 1068.344989, 
1062.2379822, 1057.449994, 1061.7179994, 1060.4010072, 1059.8690125, 
1061.7240113, 1061.7080201, 1058.3970215, 1057.8680176, 1058.2380127, 
1056.2290161, 1053.2240112, 1047.6460082, 1041.7940063, 1040.0410034, 
1040.6190063, 1045.6369994, 1050.1010009, 1128.81199335, 1132.72894074524, 
1136.05951315045, 1133.75860942184, 1126.33398461976, 1121.97836475121, 
1114.98804010824, 1104.18156200269, 1097.85760647863, 1093.48449548066, 
1089.54311267298, 1087.65328775174, 1087.83107177539, 1088.49478389202, 
1089.82480075944, 1091.87386411569, 1093.27921086657, 1096.47071830785, 
1100.97350704044, 1102.6227005604, 1102.82339384036, 1099.6516439508, 
1097.67720586025, 1097.0346199688, 1096.8465665432, 1098.06499020575, 
1100.72546732901, 1106.37447415482, 1111.91023852103, 1114.41117237617, 
1117.75201214987, 1120.7832448975, 1122.20674347869, 1120.07466752834, 
1117.94469547802, 1115.36710590868, 1109.05404401262, 1100.7222309638, 
1096.19725287201, 1087.52132174134, 1079.62024328978, 1075.06498573838, 
1068.53212719186, 1063.28239822121, 1059.64979029538, 1056.61743493392, 
1051.89577236878, 1048.42474757175, 1046.82620161254, 1044.26846536373, 
1043.14861247194, 1041.82684176033, 1041.46047397363, 1044.57471778567, 
1047.19426428227, 1051.05194873158, 1053.13842609047, 1054.50142846281, 
1051.21367146635, 1048.35332113622, 1047.56157998039, 1045.89381512512, 
1043.17345339892, 1042.61503488473, 1040.8783653719, 1039.24423257458, 
1040.09811147224, 1041.49734266536, 1042.67950374485, 1046.49669481677, 
1051.36081397707, 1055.8274040745, 1060.05336092454, 1061.8797055984, 
1063.77402125569, 1065.18506361229, 1065.29696088731, 1066.65724613614, 
1066.94988745651, 1068.16322588922, 1069.21815580453, 1069.83166801363, 
1068.92578972661, 1068.81857632408, 1070.35871095988, 1075.03883372561, 
1081.15799613269, 1086.72961878672, 1091.50584604513, 1094.58719261226, 
1097.09031664919, 1100.22361887307, 1103.94707859945, 1106.8845033995, 
1111.19264545669, 1115.10382303224, 1120.66155045774, 1125.17569412844, 
1129.42943430668, 1132.1180628489, 1134.34300733948, 1133.43510749763, 
1132.00890306928, 1129.33948182459, 1127.89952841272, 1126.73290894484, 
1126.80215199772, 1124.52480561698, 1124.50054032013, 1125.99287400392, 
1128.66498590831, 1130.96736496466, 1133.15142772993, 1137.94462318423, 
1142.78989202382, 1146.70132945013, 1151.6631122644, 1155.87424490588, 
1158.8347892958, 1161.3181459343, 1165.5259415596, 1173.38822864916, 
1181.98934506353, 1190.21226039081, 1194.81109273454, 1197.18527342649, 
1199.09715310016, 1201.08885375729, 1203.47563187564, 1205.40271083986, 
1207.24721647416, 1210.57795500043, 1213.91433880992, 1217.26535187564, 
1219.20293598272, 1220.70837160341, 1222.74566726023, 1221.94893752116, 
1220.47665680486, 1218.61792387106, 1217.58479016906, 1216.06433348629, 
1215.23248801141, 1214.29415629603, 1214.89947702975, 1217.46333121739, 
1218.76682576811, 1221.6747517902, 1223.33620352446, 1222.84608328404, 
1220.3845515427, 1217.15554472911, 1212.80167770729, 1208.2329423066, 
1204.08123494406, 1201.53635399701, 1197.84907704491, 1195.70439885016, 
1193.49731600729, 1189.93090962564, 1187.19653451844, 1185.66257561192, 
1185.77756793459, 1183.90255822654, 1182.89945696687, 1183.06617763669, 
1182.8208264332, 1183.94646343956, 1184.8534641596, 1185.84933033488, 
1187.20748792203, 1188.70677011993, 1186.75278639422, 1183.95251873763, 
1180.62084752452, 1176.63980928409, 1167.55220563799, 1159.14913329151, 
1154.47587831137, 1148.54960418648, 1145.95250178776, 1143.07035314131, 
1137.82269769928, 1133.88338944221, 1130.76687940009, 1128.18812336199, 
1120.80925075608, 1118.40550744598, 1113.93545635589, 1104.9968430839, 
1098.44571145686, 1096.38135988954, 1093.86884942387, 1090.43277224064, 
1085.63821926534, 1082.79744209722, 1083.80625856415, 1083.6723314628, 
1082.00354027587, 1077.87272739245, 1073.8896151646, 1071.01060743464, 
1070.41054586943, 1069.56096911996, 1064.84087682282, 1061.11888950636, 
1058.87994622004, 1055.5466184848, 1054.88694005768, 1053.88913948076, 
1056.96921953021, 1059.95310805114, 77.1228859956622, 81.0362538530292, 
78.8404654349793, 46.4728298378735, 33.7103494024937, 38.1634534707235, 
33.5520386736078, 26.2429467891094, 30.5979953728327, 30.5979953728327, 
31.2223518673486, 33.7665461425831, 36.6962580582319, 37.7398082531122, 
40.5860776927095, 41.0627097257687, 40.7556533339627, 52.526559398101, 
67.2093345204357, 57.3558861837519, 61.809628052695, 65.0522479908148, 
60.3356537763659, 59.9025026642582, 60.6951031882524, 60.0950548232381, 
59.3846485649388, 64.6199416069941, 64.1051430716001, 55.6515339908006, 
58.7835089189351, 55.0890845598537, 48.1838706704649, 46.0064642542491, 
48.4030879681908, 55.5793562399467, 43.3339041496164, 35.5089178322478, 
42.157901440901, 32.5975281088021, 28.6602735068277, 26.9110067493817, 
23.5372731683978, 27.6575715257538, 27.7636741048428, 28.4241344813052, 
27.7437779358905, 33.8748748481366, 38.0173561927228, 37.3614293051309, 
46.7027642395441, 51.6960358269122, 46.2684476430283, 67.9712504992444, 
67.4307596718059, 65.3539239654913, 69.3859268680975, 65.8884694613497, 
48.7463489665683, 48.3776103610145, 58.1513743683333, 53.5784372311078, 
46.4319595892114, 54.1515204375632, 48.0571628692748, 48.6571396623733, 
52.2995925118996, 44.9774509790143, 45.2591195805464, 48.7943143049565, 
56.0044804919092, 57.6982718090011, 75.947686211121, 66.6475291255686, 
63.2031704734223, 66.0494138822722, 66.2641524590373, 64.6800962380417, 
66.0941051628946, 68.6330617447997, 62.298871330898, 58.4734193157287, 
52.329016147723, 43.5650542408412, 44.6973713488007, 56.9666746925596, 
61.477502601121, 70.1850582389349, 68.3785649248245, 64.1672444920065, 
68.1060250901431, 67.2130080618559, 73.8468747118516, 69.6113702464934, 
73.1570958144156, 74.8830412236628, 85.4049570826199, 81.7882678868151, 
79.8159292966814, 65.9053697697576, 57.9091367119927, 44.4025529377091, 
43.2388424796772, 42.7803356293289, 47.7057738515549, 44.7755737074884, 
45.7557906780512, 40.016244653124, 41.4992896665767, 46.6336286507843, 
44.3657650232027, 45.4718259236287, 45.2372613787558, 56.9881807801438, 
58.8717301068573, 68.2039283244873, 73.5215112680329, 78.8594307629251, 
73.0335410836162, 71.845824268758, 73.323376014074, 89.1748677280385, 
88.8275948061702, 88.079358554904, 72.9197089804835, 66.5774741060939, 
65.5905607795046, 60.3560855296636, 60.5351059532554, 61.4085229097936, 
58.076745639994, 63.2173375817626, 67.2733875032827, 68.7459719049055, 
59.9037653356146, 44.6491666372171, 40.4929666577831, 30.2655738215587, 
36.0522832244009, 40.7505784647263, 45.517250253278, 41.5835266382263, 
41.3526668380199, 41.539756712543, 48.3189167794286, 49.8415866657383, 
44.5858982397584, 50.0675010891207, 50.5139938354098, 44.9097955003298, 
37.4247186375495, 41.3952548987526, 39.6467050713014, 39.3953595896288, 
36.8289128008105, 42.8772642627352, 37.5760511024063, 42.0791664435174, 
36.4236440580649, 25.1434697637668, 29.0666072154372, 25.3668839063101, 
34.1040319281821, 34.1351918720353, 42.138526061446, 49.3942545777117, 
53.2282422165058, 60.0907410718325, 59.6946479180297, 56.5126081396889, 
64.5584522103826, 61.6638469740838, 48.5567687748239, 50.4491176695018, 
45.8595330253583, 39.1134283844586, 22.2017732449298, 24.6509068125481, 
33.7409449463083, 27.0354908046699, 36.9033514343542, 31.849732552439, 
28.384694400023, 30.2843907497844, 30.2566110685775, 30.1702095862, 
28.1229085893699, 39.7891005017724, 37.8236546439287, 33.4844836408483, 
42.9231744072258, 49.6425369989148, 43.9761986844232, 44.7318583977582, 
37.1424843378588, 40.8120228103859, 50.807226927847, 47.9214803669887, 
44.995279725301, 41.3197867616665, 47.7401787161256, 40.9599257198947, 
48.8101085201251, 58.7773921954413, 46.8976151314924, 38.7370234461344, 
43.0052200556536, 42.7247275761847, 51.7764243779359, 47.5063348907638, 
48.4623219235214, 51.3175593621287), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1545418313.79923, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), index = structure(c(1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 
1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 1518048000, 1518134400, 1518393600, 
1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 1518739200, 1519084800, 1519171200, 
1519257600, 1519344000, 1519603200, 1519689600, 1519776000, 1519862400, 
1519948800, 1520208000, 1520294400, 1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 
1520812800, 1520899200, 1520985600, 1521072000, 1521158400, 1521417600, 
1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 1521763200, 1522022400, 1522108800, 
1522195200, 1522281600, 1522627200, 1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 
1522972800, 1523232000, 1523318400, 1523404800, 1523491200, 1523577600, 
1523836800, 1523923200, 1524009600, 1524096000, 1524182400, 1524441600, 
1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 1524787200, 1525046400, 1525132800, 
1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 
1525910400, 1525996800, 1526256000, 1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 
1526601600, 1526860800, 1526947200, 1527033600, 1527120000, 1527206400, 
1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 1527811200, 1528070400, 1528156800, 
1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 
1528934400, 1529020800, 1529280000, 1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 
1529625600, 1529884800, 1529971200, 1530057600, 1530144000, 1530230400, 
1530489600, 1530576000, 1530748800, 1530835200, 1531094400, 1531180800, 
1531267200, 1531353600, 1531440000, 1531699200, 1531785600, 1531872000, 
1531958400, 1532044800, 1532304000, 1532390400, 1532476800, 1532563200, 
1532649600, 1532908800, 1532995200, 1533081600, 1533168000, 1533254400, 
1533513600, 1533600000, 1533686400, 1533772800, 1533859200, 1534118400, 
1534204800, 1534291200, 1534377600, 1534464000, 1534723200, 1534809600, 
1534896000, 1534982400, 1535068800, 1535328000, 1535414400, 1535500800, 
1535587200, 1535673600, 1536019200, 1536105600, 1536192000, 1536278400, 
1536537600, 1536624000, 1536710400, 1536796800, 1536883200, 1537142400, 
1537228800, 1537315200, 1537401600, 1537488000, 1537747200, 1537833600, 
1537920000, 1538006400, 1538092800, 1538352000, 1538438400, 1538524800, 
1538611200, 1538697600, 1538956800, 1539043200, 1539129600, 1539216000, 
1539302400, 1539561600, 1539648000, 1539734400, 1539820800, 1539907200, 
1540166400, 1540252800, 1540339200, 1540425600, 1540512000, 1540771200, 
1540857600, 1540944000, 1541030400, 1541116800, 1541376000, 1541462400, 
1541548800, 1541635200, 1541721600, 1541980800, 1542067200, 1542153600, 
1542240000, 1542326400, 1542585600, 1542672000, 1542758400, 1542931200, 
1543190400, 1543276800, 1543363200, 1543449600, 1543536000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(212L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("y", "x1", "x2", "x3")))
```

Data 2:

```
probs <- list(c(`2018-03-02` = 0.420560689116128), c(`2018-03-05` = 0.711907085203791), 
    c(`2018-03-06` = 0.751215601254221), c(`2018-03-07` = 0.547750838805509), 
    c(`2018-03-08` = 0.593534104939348), c(`2018-03-09` = 0.527119339702333), 
    c(`2018-03-12` = 0.0723935802517959), c(`2018-03-13` = 0.147386150528317), 
    c(`2018-03-14` = 0.0110208387470279), c(`2018-03-15` = 0.448885780391426), 
    c(`2018-03-16` = 0.390256452877606), c(`2018-03-19` = 0.455819375756108), 
    c(`2018-03-20` = 0.373370265212439), c(`2018-03-21` = 0.285897356504093), 
    c(`2018-03-22` = 0.28174860433147), c(`2018-03-23` = 0.411629206184693), 
    c(`2018-03-26` = 0.602595990820247), c(`2018-03-27` = 0.914769125894976), 
    c(`2018-03-28` = 0.567802770307713), c(`2018-03-29` = 1.06192517431111), 
    c(`2018-04-02` = 1.26133164688967), c(`2018-04-03` = 0.765505424480004), 
    c(`2018-04-04` = 0.599705106418312), c(`2018-04-05` = 0.783480703900658), 
    c(`2018-04-06` = 0.58925226449577), c(`2018-04-09` = 0.581888802979559), 
    c(`2018-04-10` = 0.69731544035042), c(`2018-04-11` = 0.811834990407441), 
    c(`2018-04-12` = 0.40358830120227), c(`2018-04-13` = 0.732777147245629), 
    c(`2018-04-16` = 0.351131289433891), c(`2018-04-17` = 0.858564500915946), 
    c(`2018-04-18` = 0.398843971991605), c(`2018-04-19` = 0.232313329163781), 
    c(`2018-04-20` = 0.511838387056659), c(`2018-04-23` = 0.470527532699864), 
    c(`2018-04-24` = 0.75300602307451), c(`2018-04-25` = 1.7150087789751), 
    c(`2018-04-26` = 0.71773864194899), c(`2018-04-27` = 0.718150438655544), 
    c(`2018-04-30` = 0.60025651434085), c(`2018-05-01` = 0.516209030172394), 
    c(`2018-05-02` = 0.597683826516939), c(`2018-05-03` = 0.602186621767186), 
    c(`2018-05-04` = 0.837921470849356), c(`2018-05-07` = 0.801165076649731), 
    c(`2018-05-08` = 0.795649126872325), c(`2018-05-09` = 0.669657050275692), 
    c(`2018-05-10` = 0.432442105016062), c(`2018-05-11` = 0.241267377515004), 
    c(`2018-05-14` = 0.188621015982501), c(`2018-05-15` = -0.18303573453157), 
    c(`2018-05-16` = 0.152752056639494), c(`2018-05-17` = 0.514420711650191), 
    c(`2018-05-18` = 0.156339542628494), c(`2018-05-21` = 0.49960357405928), 
    c(`2018-05-22` = 0.711680804214282), c(`2018-05-23` = 0.460762316943894), 
    c(`2018-05-24` = 0.550255124643012), c(`2018-05-25` = 0.988972200664625), 
    c(`2018-05-29` = 0.846476234446601), c(`2018-05-30` = 0.50919230317936), 
    c(`2018-05-31` = 0.723166021404194), c(`2018-06-01` = 0.835744277153273), 
    c(`2018-06-04` = 0.525528654060598), c(`2018-06-05` = 0.620015291063136), 
    c(`2018-06-06` = 0.176251554900159), c(`2018-06-07` = 0.136995698782173), 
    c(`2018-06-08` = 0.0522471325520983), c(`2018-06-11` = 0.191934977257687), 
    c(`2018-06-12` = 0.429006006600039), c(`2018-06-13` = 0.559913925676721), 
    c(`2018-06-14` = 0.672077559523321), c(`2018-06-15` = 0.76032956322575), 
    c(`2018-06-18` = 0.92544891831305), c(`2018-06-19` = 0.464788295902493), 
    c(`2018-06-20` = 0.726125381878034), c(`2018-06-21` = 0.68716814788161), 
    c(`2018-06-22` = 1.05616788651542), c(`2018-06-25` = 0.868015147566888), 
    c(`2018-06-26` = 0.644906830154394), c(`2018-06-27` = 0.208974693095105), 
    c(`2018-06-28` = 0.138107192015791), c(`2018-06-29` = 0.166994363352344), 
    c(`2018-07-02` = -0.0251122167094578), c(`2018-07-03` = -0.177699586946273), 
    c(`2018-07-05` = -0.326862202836793), c(`2018-07-06` = 0.0201775156053099), 
    c(`2018-07-09` = 0.426881152297873), c(`2018-07-10` = 0.744979059597089), 
    c(`2018-07-11` = 0.41243241951448), c(`2018-07-12` = 0.502955033278997), 
    c(`2018-07-13` = 0.354841947278703), c(`2018-07-16` = 0.139218821204331), 
    c(`2018-07-17` = -0.202178270120416), c(`2018-07-18` = 0.128150204047404), 
    c(`2018-07-19` = -0.0686370513411129), c(`2018-07-20` = -0.0431244526756323), 
    c(`2018-07-23` = -0.0752612046047743), c(`2018-07-24` = 0.341756550136681), 
    c(`2018-07-25` = -0.0195230327845111), c(`2018-07-26` = 0.330832699288839), 
    c(`2018-07-27` = 0.828860453502682), c(`2018-07-30` = 0.709201233874251), 
    c(`2018-07-31` = 0.140975580247175), c(`2018-08-01` = 0.0294266713325949), 
    c(`2018-08-02` = -0.0309860327622304), c(`2018-08-03` = 0.328432490391903), 
    c(`2018-08-06` = 0.246261721432661), c(`2018-08-07` = 0.155023310480069), 
    c(`2018-08-08` = 0.264199818076836), c(`2018-08-09` = 0.619737926626806), 
    c(`2018-08-10` = 0.192071322493496), c(`2018-08-13` = 0.0642317026042935), 
    c(`2018-08-14` = -0.0489313867619856), c(`2018-08-15` = 0.44527540734492), 
    c(`2018-08-16` = 0.250841276758185), c(`2018-08-17` = 0.166886285921369), 
    c(`2018-08-20` = 0.14501608322908), c(`2018-08-21` = 0.299868775235037), 
    c(`2018-08-22` = 0.220950088232105), c(`2018-08-23` = 0.556141681401253), 
    c(`2018-08-24` = 0.332399640608902), c(`2018-08-27` = 0.31601373354441), 
    c(`2018-08-28` = 0.536228568950966), c(`2018-08-29` = 0.461926306171486), 
    c(`2018-08-30` = 0.454570840347704), c(`2018-08-31` = 0.226220781244086), 
    c(`2018-09-04` = 0.285296899508341), c(`2018-09-05` = 0.444687467396326), 
    c(`2018-09-06` = 0.576303992437837), c(`2018-09-07` = 0.904209619267055), 
    c(`2018-09-10` = 1.22770238231023), c(`2018-09-11` = 0.936841682214141), 
    c(`2018-09-12` = 1.05849630327662), c(`2018-09-13` = 0.637323180199244), 
    c(`2018-09-14` = 0.932850919631093), c(`2018-09-17` = 0.541733974001656), 
    c(`2018-09-18` = 0.36306729369803), c(`2018-09-19` = 0.642546689499425), 
    c(`2018-09-20` = 0.916481643939073), c(`2018-09-21` = 0.614426300203428), 
    c(`2018-09-24` = 0.508766547811766), c(`2018-09-25` = 0.338267252107242), 
    c(`2018-09-26` = 0.455102005496381), c(`2018-09-27` = 0.0598758629606586), 
    c(`2018-09-28` = 0.291185862573928), c(`2018-10-01` = 0.579664627999074), 
    c(`2018-10-02` = 0.543265160634182), c(`2018-10-03` = 0.518432853545448), 
    c(`2018-10-04` = 0.541374575635435), c(`2018-10-05` = 1.12461397204987), 
    c(`2018-10-08` = 0.701101617497031), c(`2018-10-09` = 0.610361538453297), 
    c(`2018-10-10` = 0.393709447767468), c(`2018-10-11` = 0.326895135027112), 
    c(`2018-10-12` = 0.9286505914526), c(`2018-10-15` = 1.56529837818139), 
    c(`2018-10-16` = 0.91095701538889), c(`2018-10-17` = 0.953883434361834), 
    c(`2018-10-18` = 0.653974845171448), c(`2018-10-19` = 0.417176906768297), 
    c(`2018-10-22` = 0.586281560385281), c(`2018-10-23` = 0.381443970694156), 
    c(`2018-10-24` = 0.510316238211796), c(`2018-10-25` = 0.100366157783568), 
    c(`2018-10-26` = -0.421064599732561), c(`2018-10-29` = 0.656960441730497), 
    c(`2018-10-30` = 0.494031922279178), c(`2018-10-31` = 0.597524731270041), 
    c(`2018-11-01` = 0.674525019989957), c(`2018-11-02` = 0.589723916825039), 
    c(`2018-11-05` = 0.438332501211451), c(`2018-11-06` = 0.699001705555669), 
    c(`2018-11-07` = 0.63181540579542), c(`2018-11-08` = 0.149239387764848), 
    c(`2018-11-09` = 0.272625539714475), c(`2018-11-12` = 0.524676229501674), 
    c(`2018-11-13` = 0.956295144895798), c(`2018-11-14` = 0.386944846002602), 
    c(`2018-11-15` = 0.582054913107624), c(`2018-11-16` = 0.263083233959702), 
    c(`2018-11-19` = -0.055491287398159), c(`2018-11-20` = 0.700720198889711), 
    c(`2018-11-21` = 1.24722134579426), c(`2018-11-23` = 0.88799587539072), 
    c(`2018-11-26` = 0.61561373514364), c(`2018-11-27` = 0.228747410170771), 
    c(`2018-11-28` = 0.710493869896566), c(`2018-11-29` = 0.639454784579899), 
    c(`2018-11-30` = 0.553917730992259))
```

Comment: Merging them as dataframes and going back to `xts` is not an option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939207/merge-or-cbind-xts-object-with-dataframe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297231/converting-a-data-frame-to-xts

Answer (score 1):

The following works. You either unlist or create a named vector of probs. Then you create an xts object of this, but you need to use as.Date on the names of the probs (or rownames from the data.frame) otherwise you try to merge a character value with the date values of the dat xts.

```
library(xts)

# creates a named vector
vals_probs <- sapply(probs, `[`)

# also works
# vals <- data.frame(unlist(probs))

# need to set the names as dates otherwise they are characters
probs_xts <- xts(vals, as.Date(names(vals)))


tail(merge(dat, probs_xts))
           y       x1       x2       x3 probs_xts
2018-11-23 0 1047.646 1058.880 43.00522 0.8879959
2018-11-26 1 1041.794 1055.547 42.72473 0.6156137
2018-11-27 1 1040.041 1054.887 51.77642 0.2287474
2018-11-28 1 1040.619 1053.889 47.50633 0.7104939
2018-11-29 1 1045.637 1056.969 48.46232 0.6394548
2018-11-30 1 1050.101 1059.953 51.31756 0.5539177
```